# XSLT: Copy and modify

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have a use case that does not fall into any of the other duplicate-and-modify answer.

I have the following XML fragment:

```
<Elements>
    <Irrelevant/>
    <Item>
        <Misc. subelements>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <Misc. subelements>
    </Item>
    <Irrelevant/>
    <Item>
        <Misc. subelements>
        <Name>B</Name>
        <Misc. subelements>
    </Item>
</Elements>
```

and need to transform it into the following fragment (the suffix "_x" is injected via a template parameter that is passed in, but for the answer it can just be assumed to be always "_x"):

```
<Elements>
    <Irrelevant/>
    <Item>
        <Misc. subelements (copied as-is)>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <Misc. subelements (copied as-is)>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Misc. subelements (copied as-is)>
        <Name>A_x</Name>
        <Misc. subelements (copied as-is)>
    </Item>
    <Irrelevant/>
    <Item>
        <Misc. subelements (copied as-is)>
        <Name>B</Name>
        <Misc. subelements (copied as-is)>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Misc. subelements (copied as-is)>
        <Name>B_x</Name>
        <Misc. subelements (copied as-is)>
    </Item>
</Elements>
```

i.e. each `Item` is copied once in its original form and once in its modified form. I have no problem copying the original form only or the modified form only, but differentiating whether the current context is to be copied as original or modified is posing a challenge.

Comment: Can you show us one XSLT attempt you have? Doing `<xsl:template match="Item"><xsl:copy-of select="."/><Item><Name><xsl:value-of select="Name"/>_x</Name></Item></xsl:template>` sounds straightforward. Or use a mode to handle the modification.

Comment: I forgot to mention the fact that Item contains a lot of other elements in addition to Name that I want to copy as-is (unmodified and without explicit matching). I've updated the example, and I'll try to include my XSLT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then add a template for `Item` elements

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="change"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then write a template for `Name` elements in mode `change`

```
<xsl:template match="Name" mode="change">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., $suffix)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

with a global param `<xsl:param name="suffix" select="'_x'"/>`.

Comment: I've tried to emulate the mode mechanics with an additional parameter that was dynamically evaluated because I was ignorant that something like 'mode' exists. Thank you!